# /bin/sh: 1: user: not found when running shell script using crontab

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Hi I'm getting this error when running the shell script using crontab for the specific user

this my crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
29 22 * * * automation /home/automation/profilecheck/untitled.sh >> /home/automation/profilecheck/profilecheck.log 2>&1
```

anyone can help with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Cron jobs running with `crontab -e` are run as the user who issues that command and thus owns that cronjob. You need to remove the user `automation` from your command and create/run the cronjob from `automation` user account.

```
29 22 * * * /home/automation/profilecheck/untitled.sh >> /home/automation/profilecheck/profilecheck.log 2>&1
```

O
Or you can add your cronjob into `/etc/crontab`

Or move your cronjob to `/etc/cron.d` and make sure the user is available and has relevant permissions.

Comment: if i remove the user(automation) the cronjob is running but it's getting an permission denied error when trying to ssh to other server.

Comment: i added /home to the path and Im getting different error now.
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home
/bin/sh: 1: automation: Permission denied

Comment: If you want the user then can you move it to `/etc/cron.d` and let the system run it with the user?

Comment: so i just need to move my crontab file to /etc/cron.d folder?

Comment: Yes, or you try updating /etc/crontab also, I have updated the answer